# How to identify multiple instances of Glance App Widget

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-appwidget, glance-appwidget

I am trying to create a widget which shows information about a hardware device.
There can be multiple of these devices and user will be able to add same widget for different devices.
I am looking for a way to understand which device information should be shown inside `GlanceAppWidget.Content()` method. In Classical Android Widgets it was possible by checking appWidgetId passed to `update()` method. At Glance appWidgetId is hidden intentionally but I could not find an alternative solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will use a configuration activity when the widget is placed to select the device right?

You can then use the GlanceID to store data in the state of that specific instance (`updateAppWidgetState())`. Then inside the Content you can retrieve the `currentState` to know which hardware device needs to be shown.